# Sort array of objects alphabetically but numbers should be at bottom objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to sort array of objects alphabetically but numbers should be at last or bottom. I have a objects(type is People and sort is base on name which is attribute of people class) of mutable array which is `_filteredArray` defined in my following code.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [_filteredArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
_filteredArray = [self createMutableArray1:sortedArray];
return [_filteredArray count];
```

above code is sorting alphabetically but numbers are showing at the top, which is not my desired result, want to show at bottom after alphabets. Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Translate numbers to a higher value before sorting.  (Do this in the sort helper function, of course, not in the array data.)

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me any example for this task or any helping link?

Comment: Well, I'd use a function or comparator.  Inside said function get each string, scan it, and for each character that's numeric (and you want to handle this way), add 0x100 (or more, if you're dealing with non-ASCII characters.  (Probably easiest to do the scan/update on a mutable string.)  Then just return the `compare` of the two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one for your contribution, I finally done by getting bit help from internet and change this for my own requirement. Can look into my following code.

```
  NSArray *sorted = [phoneContacts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    /* NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending */
    SCPhoneContact *contact1 = (SCPhoneContact *)obj1;
    SCPhoneContact *contact2 = (SCPhoneContact *)obj2;

    BOOL isPunct1 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)contact1.name characterAtIndex:0]];
    BOOL isPunct2 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)contact2.name characterAtIndex:0]];
    if (isPunct1 && !isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (!isPunct1 && isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }


    return [(NSString*)contact1.name compare:contact2.name options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

`SCPhoneContact` my Objects and`phoneContacts` is array of these objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know this is perfect solution. But this will work.

```
- (void)sortArray {
    NSMutableArray *arrayToSort = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"asd",@"1",@"sr",@"42.0",@"bs",@"0", nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray;

    sortedArray = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *first, NSString *second) {

        if([self isNumeric:first] && [self isNumeric:second]) {
            return [first compare:second options:NSNumericSearch];
        }
        if ([self isNumeric:first]) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if ([self isNumeric:second]) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return [first compare:second options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }];

}

//Method which find whether the string is numeric or not
- (BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString *)string {
     BOOL isNumeric = FALSE;
     NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
     isNumeric = [scanner scanDouble:NULL] && [scanner isAtEnd];
     return isNumeric;
}
```

Comment: This **does not work**, because if you pass in two numeric strings they aren't even compared.

Comment: @Jenox. Yes you are correct. The above code only sorts the alphabets and lets the numbers at the bottom of the array

Comment: @Jenox. I have updated the answer. Now it sorts the numbers also.